# Why can I no longer upload a picture anywhere on the Stack Exchange network?

Tags: support, bug, images, uploader

For some reason I can no longer upload a picture *anywhere* on the Stack Exchange network. When prompted to "Drag and Drop or Click here" to upload a picture, the prompt is unresponsive. I also cannot add a link to the photo.

As well as the above symptoms, small red text is constantly displayed on the bottom of the window saying, "Your image is too large to upload (over 2 MiB)", before I've even upload a picture yet. In fact, this "bug", is the very thing preventing me from providing a picture of this undesired behavior.

My current browser is Google Chrome, Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit). Could anyone confirm if this is something local to me - or if this is affecting all users?

Comment: Do you have a Norton Antivirus extension enabled in Chrome? If so try it with it disabled. If not, or if that doesn't work, try in an incognito tab. Btw, in any case, consider updating Chrome.

Comment: @JasonC Alright, I'll try that and get back to you.

Comment: @JasonC Would it be appropriate to ask for this question to be reopened because the fix to my problem was a bit different? While the linked duplicate helped, my problem was a combination of several different ad-blocking, and password-securing extensions, not Norton Toolbar.

Comment: You could add your solution as an answer to the other question. This way all different ways to handle the same problem would be in one place.

Comment: ^ That is the most helpful thing to do.